# map AWS instances/volumes to snapshots with boto

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto

I'm writing a **python** script to check all my running instances for **ebs** snapshots...

```
rsv = self.botoEC2.get_all_instances()
for r in rsv:
  ins = r.instances[0]
  blockDevice = self.getInstanceAttribute(ins,"blockDeviceMapping")
  print blockDevice

def getInstanceAttribute(self,instance,attribute):
    return instance.get_attribute(attribute)
```

output:

```
{u'blockDeviceMapping': {u'/dev/sda1': <boto.ec2.blockdevicemapping.BlockDeviceType object at 0x10d5faed0>}}
```

I am new to boto.  Am I on the right path?

Do I need to get the `blockDeviceMapping` first, then call the volume functions?

How do I get the actual volume id, so i can check it for existing snapshots?

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you want to loop through all of your running instances and then loop through all of the EBS volumes attached to those instances.  Is that right?  If so, I would do something like this:

```
import boto

ec2 = boto.connect_ec2()
reservations = ec2.get_all_instances(filters={'instance-state-name': 'running'})
volumes = []
for r in reservations:
    for i in r.instances:
        volumes.extend(ec2.get_all_volumes(filters={'attachment.instance-id': i.id}))
```

At that point, volumes would contain a list of all Volume objects that are attached to running EC2 instances.